# Loop for difference in dates between two columns

Tags: excel, vba, date, datetime

I try to get the difference between dates between two columns, U and S. When I manually replace the PRow with actual number (eg:1), the column AD give the result as expected.
But when I try to loop them using the incremental PRow as for row position, it appears

```
Run-time error '1004':
Apllication-defined or object-defined error
```

Here is my coding :

```
Dim FRow As Long
Dim lrow As Long
Dim PRow As Long

Range("AD1").Value = "Response Time"

Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Set CurrentSheet = Excel.ActiveSheet

Dim Date1 As Date
Dim Date2 As Date

For PRow = lrow To FRow Step -1

FRow = CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
lrow = CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Rows(CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row

Date1 = DateValue(CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "U").Value)
Date2 = DateValue(CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "S").Value)
CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AD").Value = Day(Date1) - Day(Date2)

Next PRow
```

So, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should assign your variables *before* you use it as loop range :-)
Otherwise FRow and lrow will be 0.

```
FRow = CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1).Row 
lrow = CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Rows(CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row

For PRow = lrow To FRow Step -1
   ....
```

Comment: Thanks @Fratyx ! I mislooked them :D